# Error concatenate string+byte

Tags: python, types

I've the variable buffer(string) and eip(byte) and I want concatenate to buffer.

My code:

```
junk = "\x41" * 50 # A
eip = pack("<L", 0x0015FCC4) # false jmp register
buffer = junk + eip # Problem HERE
print(buffer)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Well, I can't convert eip to string, because if I convert eip to string with str(eip), the output is: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAb'\xc4\xfc\x15\x00'

I just want that buffer contain the hexadecimal string to use it, and for this reason I put the print (for debug).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following returns 'c4fc1500'

```
import binascii
binascii.hexlify(eip)
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: I can't understand why admins duplicate and modify my post...
This is my post: stackoverflow.com/questions/22290915/convert-hexadecimal-to-normal-string

Comment: @user3270009 Perhaps you should write an "expected output" part to distinguish your problem from others.